# How to call a callback function in a PHP class

Tags: php

I want to use array_filter to remove those items in an array whose value is equal to a specific character like '.' . To do, so I used the following code but I don't know how to pass the callback function to array_filter:

```
    class Myclass(){
            private function isPunc($var){
        if($var=='.'){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
        public function myfunction($arr){
         $arr = array_filter($arr,"isPunc");
    }

    }
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have some errors in your code, missing `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Myclass(){

    private function isPunc($var) {
        if ($var=='.') {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function myfunction($arr) {
         $arr = array_filter($arr, array($this,'isPunc'));
    }

}
```

Comment: You have the parameters mixed up, it is the Array first and the callback second.

Answer (score 2):

use `$arr = array_filter($arr, array($this, 'isPunc'));`

Answer (score 0):

array_filter() expects a Callable. This is an special internal type in PHP that can be on of four things:

1. a string with function name
2. an array with an object and method name as elements
3. an anonymous function
4. a functor (an object that implements __invoke)

In your case the second variant should work:

```
class FilterIsDot {

  private function accept($element) {
    if($element == '.'){
      return TRUE;
    }else{
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  public function filter($array) {
    return array_filter(
      $array, array($this, 'accept')
    );
  }
}

$in = array('.', 'foo');

$filter = new FilterIsDot();
var_dump($filter->filter($in));
```

I would suggest a different approach avoiding array_filter(). SPL contains a FilterIterator class. You can extends this class:

```
class FilterIsDot extends FilterIterator {

  public function __construct($arrayOrIterator) {
    parent::__construct(
      is_array($arrayOrIterator) 
        ? new ArrayIterator($arrayOrIterator) 
        : $arrayOrIterator
    );
  }

  public function accept() {
    if($this->current() == '.') {
      return TRUE;
    }else{
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}

$in = array('.', 'foo');

$filter = new FilterIsDot($in);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($filter));
```

In this case the filter works on the fly. It is only used if the elements are actually accessed.